# Pandas - change the shape of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'level': ['ma', 'ma', 'phd', 'phd'],
                   'measure': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
                   'result_1': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'result_2': [50, 60, 70, 80]})
```

And I want to change the shape of `df` into this:

```
           level    x     y
result_1      ma    1     2
             phd    3     4

result_2      ma    50    60
             phd    70    80
```

I don't know the correct code of my desired outcome so I just posted the output that I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `set_index` then `unstack` level=0 to nest under column headers and `T` to transpose:

```
df.set_index(['level','measure']).unstack(0).T
#To @Alexander point in the comments, alternative for readability.
#df.set_index(['level','measure']).unstack(level=0).T
```

Output:

```
measure          x   y
         level        
result_1 ma      1   2
         phd     3   4
result_2 ma     50  60
         phd    70  80
```

Comment: I believe it is more readable to explicitly name the unstacked index, e.g. `unstack('level')`. Otherwise very good.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way from `stack` and `unstack` + `swaplevel`

```
df.set_index(['measure','level']).stack().unstack(0).swaplevel(0,1).sort_index(level=0)
Out[256]: 
measure          x   y
         level        
result_1 ma      1   2
         phd     3   4
result_2 ma     50  60
         phd    70  80
```